# Carpet squeaky, SqueakNoMore Drill Settings

Tags: flooring, carpet

I am using a Squeak No More Kit to fix up a squeaky, creaky carpet.
For my power drill, what should my (a) gear switch and (b) torque control be set at?

This is used to drill plywood subfloor into a floor joist. I just want to be sure, and the directions don't specify. http://go.rockler.com/tech/Squeeeeek-No-More-Floor-Squeak-Repair-Kit-Instructions.pdf

I have a [Dewalt drill here](https://www.homedepot.com/p/DEWALT-ATOMIC-20-Volt-MAX-Cordless-Brushless-Compact-1-2-in-Drill-Driver-2-20-Volt-1-3Ah-Batteries-Charger-Bag-DCD708C2/308067442) :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gUW-IhSMBc

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you did not have some Rep I would have flagged. Most screws require clockwise rotation to sink looking at the joist finding screw it looked right handed or clockwise also.

Comment: Never used those. I'm guessing the stand-off keeps you from over driving them. A torque setting would just keep the head from being stripped while it disengages, which doesn't matter because you snap them off with a hammer later? It *would* matter if you stripped it before you got it all the way in *because* you used 'low settings'. - Use 3rd gear, and set to 'drill'. - Practice on some scrap to get a feel for when/if the screws will snap themselves. Otherwise, they're just screws....

Comment: Are you sure the squeaking is coming from movement between the plywood and the joists? I had a similar problem in a rental I was remodeling.  Since all the floor covering was removed I put a bunch more screws in the floor....didn't fix the problem.  It turned out squeaking came from the joist hangers that got loose.  adding screws to them to tighten them up fixed the squeaking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For my power drill, what should my (a) gear switch and (b) torque control be set at?

For *screwing* you want the drill on the low speed-range for higher torque (i.e., more driving power).

As for your clutch setting, you should set it low initially and increase if/when it fails to drive your screw to the stop point on the jig. When you raise it enough to drive to the stop point, leave it at that setting (or 1 point above that). The reason the clutch setting is not specified is because different materials require different clutch settings, and different drivers have different clutch release points associated with their clutch setpoints.

Comment: Clutch settings are always *verify in field* depending on how hard the work is, +1. But screw guns always belong in 3rd gear (with a fresh battery) unless you're drilling steel IMO (then you shouldn't be using batteries). If it's going too slow you have to fight static friction.

Comment: so I see numbers 1-15 in the dewalt drill picture above, are you saying put it at 15 for plywood floor?

Comment: @mattsmith5 - presumably, you actually read the full instructions and the answer above. How did you arrive at 15?